# PgAdmin4 is slowing down the brower when displaying large amount of geometric features from a PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, pgadmin-4

After having run a basic `SELECT` statement on a table with geometric features in a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database, when selecting (i.e. by clicking on its header in the "Data output" tab in the bottom panel) a geometry column which has roughly ~2500 small lines and by clicking on the viewer button (green square):

[image]

[pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/) ([dockerized](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/) v.6.13) is taking too long to respond, at a point where this warning shows up in my [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) (104.0.1 - 64-bit) browser / Ubuntu 22.04:

[image]

It can take ages (more than 1 minute sometimes, up to several minutes during which pgAdmin4 is totally unresponsive) to actually display the features on the embedded OSM map in the "Geometry Viewer" tab in the bottom panel. The same operation was super fast (less than 1 second) on previous version (e.g. v.6.8).

Do you know if there is some hidden option to set up so that I can retrieve the speed of previous versions of pgAdmin4 when viewing some large amount of geometric feature on the map? Or why is it going so slow since a few versions and how to fix that?